# What is the Standard to protect classified, Secret and Top Secret information?

Tags: encryption, fips

Para 3 of Security Requirements for Cryptographic Module ([FIPS 140-2](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.140-2.pdf)) specifies the requirements that will be satisfied by a crypto module protecting sensitive but unclassified information.

What are the standards to protect classified, Secret and Top Secret information?

Comment: I believe that those standards are themselves classified

Comment: Sorry, but has any of you been in any service?

Comment: @Someonewhoknows: if it's classified, someone who knows isn't allowed to say...

Answer (score 1):

Data classified up to top secret may be handled by [CNSA algorithms](https://web.archive.org/web/20211230155059/https://apps.nsa.gov/iaarchive/programs/iad-initiatives/cnsa-suite.cfm) (e.g. AES-256, RSA 3072, etc.)  Above that, as poncho noted, the algorithms themselves are classified.

Comment: Which begs for: how are the levels above top secret named and defined?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is nothing above top secret.  I believe the levels are controlled unclassified and then the three classified levels: confidential, secret and top secret.

Comment: "Code word" is above top secret: https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2017/05/trump-russia-code-word/526833/

Comment: "Codeword" is not "above," it is "to the side." See the discussion of the lattice model in Ross Anderson's book "Security Engineering." For example, the codeword "Crypto" could be appended to a "Secret" classification to make it "{Secret, Crypto}." You would need both Secret and Crypto clearance to read it.

Comment: @Swashbuckler ECI (Exceptionally Classified Information) is above Top Secret, but it is handled on a different scale and is not to be stored physically or digitally. As such, there are no algorithms that protect it.

Comment: @forest any references that mention ECI?